# List Items moving when window is zoomed out?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days.  I can fix the problem, but fixing it that way doesn't give me the desired effect.

When I zoom out, one of my list items drops to the next line.  How can I stop this from happening?

Here's a fiddle, if you zoom out you'll see "Three" drops to the next line **http://jsfiddle.net/j5u2Q/**

If I remove borders from .middle and increase the padding so it's the exact same width, the problem doesn't present itself?  Is there's a problem with borders?

```
#banner li.middle {padding: 0 16px; border-left: 1px solid #959595; border-right: 1px solid #959595;}
```

Thanks,

Comment: If I were you I would change specific width to percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `min-width` and `max-width` to your containers. Same for height if need be. Borders do add margining to your element as well, making it however many defined pixels (or zoomed in pixels) larger on each side.

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/kESUR/)

Answer (score 1):

Have you try

```
#container {width: 100%;}
```